# Xamarin.Forms. Navigate from detail to master page on swipe

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, swipe-gesture

There is a list on the main page. When you tap on item opens page with full data about that item (Navigation.PushAsync). I need to implement on Android and iOS, so that when you swipe back on master page(Navigation.PopAsync).

As below shown:

[image: swipe]

I am using SwipeGestureRecognizer. But the animation itself (pull the page) I do not have.
How to implement this on gif above?

Comment: Are you using a master-detail page ?

Comment: To use `SwipeGestureRecognizer`, you should write the animation yourself. To use system animation,  you can refer to https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/127373/xamarin-forms-swipe-back-to-previous-page. By using system animation, the `gestureRecongnize` will only be trigged when you swipe from the left edge.

Comment: @jackHua I referred to https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/127373/xamarin-forms-swipe-back-to-previous-page but there only animation for iOS

Comment: @FabriBertani Yes

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm not good at Android. My link is about implement of iOS.

Comment: @jackHua but I need two platforms. And not only from the left side to pull, but from any place could pull